# Sending $_POST without submitting a form?

Tags: php

I'm working on a script for forms that submits the data to itself to check for errors, if there are no errors it uses header() to send them to the next page. Is there a way I can send the $_POST data to the next page as well without the form being re-submitted?

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $errors = array();
    $moo = array();

    if (empty($_POST['a'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to answer Question 1!<br/>';
    } else {
        $moo = $_POST['a'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['b'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to answer Question 2!<br/>';
    }

    if (empty($_POST['c'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to answer Question 3!<br/>';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {

        $_POST['aids'] = "RAWR";
        $url = "http://localhost/test/test.php?page=2";
        header("Location: $url");
        exit();
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
}

echo "
    <form action=\"test.php?page=1\" method=\"post\">
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"a\" value=\"" . $_POST['a'] . "\">
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"b\" value=\"" . $_POST['b'] . "\">
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"c\" value=\"" . $_POST['c'] . "\">
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\">
    </form>
";

?>
```

Comment: save it to a file or database?

Comment: have you tried using `.ajax()` ?

Comment: Do the error checking in JS.  Or, if wanting to scrictly use PHP, you can save them in sessions and pass it along.  Or, the suggested way is do the error checking and use the data within the same file.

Comment: Why don't you include the processing script and do the redirect when the processing is done. Sounds more logical to me at least.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an AJAX request to check for errors, and then submit the form if all info is correct to the location of $url.

But if you want to store the data in a $_SESSION variable upon no error, you will be able to retrieve it on the next page.

```
...
if (empty($errors)) {

    $_POST['aids'] = "RAWR";
    $url = "http://localhost/test/test.php?page=2";
    $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
} else {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}
...
```

could even send the data with the querystring of the url like

```
$url = "http://localhost/test/test.php?page=2&data=whatever";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many ways that you could go about this. The first ones that come to mind are storing the data in a `$_SESSION` variable, then comes storing it in a database...

If you don't want to change your script's structure that much, instead of doing a redirect once the data is validated, just to an `include()` to run the other page's code -

```
if (empty($errors)) {
  ...
  // this will simply insert the contents of the script and execute it.
  include('test.php?page=2');
} else {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try using nothing as the action url. This makes the current page the target:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

EDIT. Misread question. Try this on the first page:

```
<?php  
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // check for errors here...
    if (empty($errors)) {
      $valuea = 'a';
      $valueb = 'b';
      $url = "http://domain/test/test.php?vala=".$valuea."&valb=".$valueb."";
      header("Location: $url");
      exit();
    }
  }       
?>
```

On the 2nd Page

```
<?php
$valuea = $_GET['vala'];
$valueb = $_GET['valb'];
?>
```

This is just passing the value through a url. Otherwise you'll need a session or a database to pass the values using PHP.

Comment: They are already submitting it to the first page and know how to do that - they are asking how to get that information on the second page they redirect to as well.

Comment: do your error checking and then do a redirect if it's successful. Or use ajax. Or use a session. There are lots of options!

Comment: Yes, but your answer doesn't address the question at all, you restate doing what they have already done successfully, not how to pass them to a second page.

Comment: updated. sorry i misread your question i thought you were asking something else.